# I can't submit reviews/ratings in Software Center

Tags: software-center

If I try and submit a review it keeps loading quite some time with the message "Bewertung wird übertragen", which means "Rating is being submitted" in German.
For example I tried to review Easystroke, but I had that problem with every package I've tried to rate yet.

I'm using Xubuntu 12.10.
Do you know of any fix for this?